# Possible to avoid $unwind / aggregation on large array using $elemMatch and regular query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents (call it 'logs') which looks similar to this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52f523892491e4d58e85d70a"),
  "ds_id" : "534d35d72491de267ca08e96",
  "eT" : NumberLong(1391784000),
  "vars" : [{
      "n" : "ActPow",
      "val" : 73.4186401367188,
      "u" : "kWh",
      "dt" : "REAL",
      "cM" : "AVE",
      "Q" : 99
    }, {
      "n" : "WinSpe",
      "val" : 3.06327962875366,
      "u" : "m/s",
      "dt" : "REAL",
      "cM" : "AVE",
      "Q" : 99
    }]
}
```

The `vars` array holds about 150 subdocuments, not just the two I have shown above. What I'd like to do now is to run a query which retrieves the `val` of the two subdocuments in the `vars` array that I have shown above.

Using the aggregation framework, I've been able to come up with the following:

```
db.logs.aggregate( [ 
    { $match : 
        { ds_id: "534d35d72491de267ca08e96", 
          eT: { $lt : 1391784000 }, 
          vars: { $elemMatch: { n: "PowCrvVld", val: 3 }}
        }
    }, 
    { $unwind : "$vars" }, 
    { $match :
        { "vars.n" : { $in : ["WinSpe", "ActPow"] }}, 
        { $project : { "vars.n" : 1, N : 1}
    } 
]);
```

While this works, I run up against the 16MB limit when running larger queries. Seeing as I have about 150 subdocuments in the `vars` array, I'd also like to avoid `$unwind` if it's possible.

Using a regular query and using `$elemMatch` I have been able to retrieve ONE of the values:

```
db.logs.TenMinLog.find({
    ds_id : "534d35d72491de267ca08e96",
    eT : { $lt : 1391784000 },
    vars : { $elemMatch : { n : "PowCrvVld", val : 3 }
    }
}, {
    ds_id : 1,
    vars : { $elemMatch : { n : "ActPow", cM : "AVE" }
});
```

What my question comes down to is if there's a way to use $elemMatch on an array multiple times in the `<projection>` part of find. If not, is there another way to easily retrieve those two subdocuments without using $unwind? I am also open to other suggestions that would be more performant that I may not be aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MongoDB 2.6 you can use the [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator to prune the elements from the vars array.

In MongoDB 2.6 you can also return results as a cursor to avoid the 16MB limit. From the docs:

> In MongoDB 2.6 the aggregate command can return results as a cursor or
>   store the results in a collection, which are not subject to the size
>   limit. The db.collection.aggregate() returns a cursor and can return
>   result sets of any size.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly consider a move to MongoDB version 2.6. Aggregation has been enhanced to return a cursor which eliminates the 16MB document limit:

> Changed in version 2.6:
>
> The db.collection.aggregate() method returns a cursor and can return
>   result sets of any size. Previous versions returned all results in a
>   single document, and the result set was subject to a size limit of 16
>   megabytes.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Also there are a number of enhancements that you may find useful for more complex aggregation queries:

> Aggregation Enhancements
>
> The aggregation pipeline adds the ability to return result sets of any
>   size, either by returning a cursor or writing the output to a
>   collection. Additionally, the aggregation pipeline supports variables
>   and adds new operations to handle sets and redact data.
>
> The db.collection.aggregate() now returns a cursor, which enables the
>   aggregation pipeline to return result sets of any size. Aggregation
>   pipelines now support an explain operation to aid analysis of
>   aggregation operations. Aggregation can now use a more efficient
>   external-disk-based sorting process.
>
> New pipeline stages:
>
> - $out stage to output to a collection.
> - $redact stage to allow additional control to accessing the data.
>
> New or modified operators:
>
> - set expression operators.
> - $let and $map operators to allow for the use of variables.
> - $literal operator and $size operator.
> - $cond expression now accepts either an object or an array.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works.

```
db.logs.TenMinLog.find({
    ds_id : "534d35d72491de267ca08e96",
    eT : { $lt : 1391784000 },
    vars : { $or: [{ $elemMatch : { n : "PowCrvVld", val : 3 },
                   { $elemMatch : { n : <whatever>, val : <whatever> }]
           }
    }
}, {
    ds_id : 1,
    vars : { $elemMatch : { n : "ActPow", cM : "AVE" }
});
```

Hope it works as you want.

Comment: This will add an additional filter in the query, but what I am asking is that I'd like to have multiple elements from the `vars` array in my projection.