# Extract two sub array values in mongodb by $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, sub-array

Aggregate, $unwind and $group is not my solution as they make query very slow, there for I am looking to get my record by db.collection.find() method.

The problem is that I need more then one value from sub array. For example from the following example I want to get the **"type" : "exam"** and **"type" : "quiz"** elements.

```
{
    "_id" : 22,
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 75.04996547553947
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 10.23046475899236
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 96.72520512117761
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 6.488940333376703
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking something like

```
db.students.find(
// Search criteria
{ '_id': 22 },

// Projection
{ _id: 1, scores: { $elemMatch: { type: 'exam', type: 'quiz' } }}
)
```

The result should be like

```
{ "_id": 22, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "type" : "quiz" } ] }
```

But this over ride the **type: 'exam'** and returns only **type: 'quiz'**. Have anybody any idea how to do this with **db.find()**?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible directly using `find` and `elemMatch` because of following limitation of `elemMatch` and `mongo array fields`.

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition. ref. from [$elemMacth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

and mongo array field limitations as below

> Only one positional $ operator may appear in the projection document.
>
> The query document should only contain a single condition on the array field being projected. Multiple conditions may override each other internally and lead to undefined behavior. ref from [mongo array field limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation)

So either you tried following this to find out only `exam` or `quiz`

```
db.collectionName.find({"_id":22,"scores":{"$elemMatch":{"type":"exam"}}},{"scores.$.type":1}).pretty()
```

is shows only `exam` scores array.

Otherwise you should go through `aggregation`

Comment: Thanks for replying @yogesh, plz let me know what will be best aggregation for less time query.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599943/mongodbs-performance-on-aggregation-queries or used indexing and sharding

Comment: I have already indexes and sharding is not an option, I have tried lots of aggregation's options but unwinding makes query way slow, that's why I was looking any solution in find().

Comment: @SajjadAhmed may be this will help you better 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018161/possible-to-avoid-unwind-aggregation-on-large-array-using-elemmatch-and-regu

Comment: @SajjadAhmed how can i help you?? have you still some concerns?

Comment: Thanks for your attention Dineshaws, I am facing problem with query return time, I tried a lot of options in db.find() and aggregation() but can't reduce time consuming while querying. So if you can help me out to provide best solution I will be very thankful.

Comment: I am using **db.collection.find({ "date_time": { "$gte": 1428883200000, "$lte": 1429487999000}, "device_id": 30, "gateway_id": 2 }).sort({"date_time": 1}) **, but it takes 3 to 5 sec which is to much.